# Passing diferent parameters of diferent object based on if condition

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I know the title is not the best to describe the problem, but i try my best here.

So basicly i am working with c# + asp + openxml and i have something like this:

```
  anchor.Append(
      new DW.HorizontalPosition(
                new DW.PositionOffset(MathOpenXml.centimetersToEMU(1.1).ToString())
                new DW.HorizontalAlignment(haPosition)
            )
            {
                RelativeFrom =
                  DW.HorizontalRelativePositionValues.Margin
            }
        );
```

the horizontalPosition object can just receive 1 object, but they have different types, my main problem is that i can't do a if statement inside there, i need to check before for example if offset != null, if it is pass just then offset as parameter if not pass the other object.

I have no idea how to archive that, any help?

Comment: Your question is not very clear. When you say 1) horizontalPosition can receive one object are you talking about its constructor that can take in only one object? and 2) "I can't do a if statement inside there", where do you mean by "there"?

Comment: ok, you are right, i mean the constuctor yes, it can receive just 1 object or the PositionOFfset or the horizontal Alignament

Comment: 2) i mean inside the constructor, if i could i could just say ok you want offset put the offset there if not put horizontal alignament

Comment: Does this code even compile? `new DW.HorizontalPosition` seems to have 2 parameters, but the separator comma is missing.It is difficult to understand code that does not compile.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes Hard to be sure, but I *think* those two are the different objects OP is trying to pass to the constructor, separately, based on a condition. In which case, OP really should read up on the ternary operator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `HorizontalPosition` class has overloaded constructors, i.e. several constructors with different parameter lists. Since overload resolution happens at compile time, you cannot pass parameters of different types at runtime.

You need to have 2 separate calls, each one calling a diffferent overload of the constructor

```
anchor.Append(
    condition
        ? new DW.HorizontalPosition(
              new DW.PositionOffset(MathOpenXml.centimetersToEMU(1.1).ToString())
          ) { RelativeFrom = DW.HorizontalRelativePositionValues.Margin }
        : new DW.HorizontalPosition(
              new DW.HorizontalAlignment(haPosition)
          ) { RelativeFrom = DW.HorizontalRelativePositionValues.Margin }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not make two constructors for HorizontalPosition, where the first constructor takes one object and the second constructor takes two?

Or you can have just one constructor which takes two parameters and you can put your if condition in the constructor block.

Comment: I was going to suggest the exact same thing. +1 for two good options.

Comment: i can't build the constructor, it is pre defined by openXML lib